# Trying to find the number of words without counting the spaces

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the number of words in from the input by user but i am asked not to find it through counting the spaces since the user can input a single letter and a bunch of spaces and it will count it as number of words

I have tried it with counting the number of spaces but i can not think of another way to count the number of words

```
char Array[100];
    {
        //variable declaration
        int words = 0;
        // input
        cout << "Enter string: ";
        cin.getline(Array, 100);
        // Number of words
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Array); i++)
        {
            if (Array[i] == ' ')
                words++;
        }
        cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words + 1;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

I want to find the number of words with another method rather than counting it through the number of spaces.Any help is appreciated.I am a beginner so could you not use something complicated to solve the problem like a getloc.

Comment: Count the words instead of spaces?

Comment: The spaces indicate the gaps between the words. So go through the whole input and keep track if you are currently in a word, or in a gap between words - the trick is to know when you swap from "in a word" to "in a gap" and vice versa. You would also be a lot better off to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and the `string` version of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), but for some (imho, bad) reason, schools often disallow this.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to count words without using space.

Comment: @BoBTFish *you have to know how to implement everything in STL before using it!*. Schools will probably have students reimplement a C++17 compiler before allowing them to use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the following change and bob's your uncle :)

```
if(array[i] == ' ') {
    continue;
}
words++;
while(array[i] != ' ') {
    i++;
}
```

Comment: it still counts if the first letter is an space

Answer (score 2):

You just have to count the number of times the space character is followed immediately by a non-space character.

```
int firstNonSpace = 0;

while (Array[firstNonSpace] ==  ' ') //to skip spaces at the beginning of input
{
     firstNonSpace++;
}
for (int i = firstNonSpace; i < strlen(Array) - 1; i++) 
{
    if (Array[i] == ' ' && Array[i+1] != ' ')
        words++;
}

if(words || firstNonSpace == 0) 
     words++; //do not increment if the input is empty or only spaces.
cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words;
```

See [**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LRj4hFLkzBCYOzK0)

Note that you will have to handle the case when the input exceeds the bounds of the array so as not to run into undefined behavior.

Comment: This code does not count the first word in the input if it is not preceded with a space

Comment: Actually the `words` variable is incremented by 1 before it is printed. Please see the `cout ` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes but if the input starts with a space, the cout will go wrong by adding `+1`. So you need to add a condition to handle this case.

Comment: @Fareanor: Yes, now I have handled that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @P.W also, if they are no words in the input at all (ie, all spaces), the `+1` would be erroneous. There is no reason to use `+1` on the result if you calculate the result properly to begin with

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Agree. Actually, I wanted to propose a solution similar to yours but was not sure if the OP was at the stage to understand stringstreams and operations on them.

Comment: @P.W that is why I also offered non stream solutions in my answer

Comment: This code is wrong. Try a single word without spaces. Expected 1 - result 0. I tried with your live demo..

Comment: @dingalapadum: I did not update the link after making changes. You can test now.

Comment: You also updated the answer with ‚|| firstspace ==0‘. This edit now fixed the bug I mentioned ;)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to let the standard library parse the words for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main () {
    //variable declarations
    std::string line, word;
    int words = 0;
    // input
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    // Number of words
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> word) {
        ++words;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use `std::string` (ie, to avoid memory allocations), you could do this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    //variable declarations
    char Array[100];
    int words = 0;
    // input
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::cin.getline(Array, 100);
    // Number of words
    char *ptr = Array;
    char *end = ptr + std::cin.gcount();
    while (ptr != end) {
        ptr = std::find_if(ptr, end, [](char c){ return !std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });
        if (ptr == end) break;
        ptr = std::find_if(ptr+1, end, [](char c){ return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });
        ++words;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to completely avoid standard library algorithms:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //variable declarations
    char Array[100];
    int words = 0;
    // input
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::cin.getline(Array, 100);
    // Number of words
    char *ptr = Array;
    char *end = ptr + std::cin.gcount();
    while (ptr != end) {
        while ((*ptr <= ' ')) && (ptr != end)) ++ptr;
        if (ptr == end) break;
        ++ptr;
        while ((ptr != end) && (*ptr > ' ')) ++ptr;
        ++words;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You could then wrap the parsing into a helper function to clean up the counting loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
//#include <algorithm>
//#include <cctype>

bool findNextWord(char* &begin, char *end) {
    /*
    begin = std::find_if(begin, end, [](char c){ return !std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });
    if (begin == end) return false;
    begin = std::find_if(begin+1, end, [](char c){ return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });
    return true;
    */
    while ((begin != end) && (*begin <= ' ')) ++begin;
    if (begin == end) return false;
    ++begin;
    while ((begin != end) && (*begin > ' ')) ++begin;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    //variable declarations
    char Array[100];
    int words = 0;
    // input
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::cin.getline(Array, 100);
    // Number of words
    char *ptr = Array;
    char *end = ptr + std::cin.gcount();
    while (findNextWord(ptr, end)) {
        ++words;
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words in the string are: " << words << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using iss was a good idea. Changing its original functionality to count words instead of recognizing space seperated integers accepted as a string :)

Comment: What does the overloaded >> operator return on writing iss >> word?

Comment: @kesarling The usual; a reference to the input stream (i.e. `iss`).

Comment: Then how does it run the while loop? I mean, doesn't the loop require a number (other than zero of course) to run?

Comment: @kesarling a stream carries state information, and implements `operator bool()` and `bool operator!()` to report that state. If `operator>>` reaches the end of the stream, the stream is set to an eof state. If `operator>>` encounters an error, the stream is set to an error state. When the `while` loop evaluates `iss` (the return value of `operator>>`) as a boolean and sees the steam is in an eof or error state, the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking online and found them all very confusing this is simple and works

```
string state;//variable for statement the user may enter 
int i; //variable for the for loop 
int wordtally; // variable for word count 

    //this checks if its a space or not and then if it is a space it loops untill it
//reaches a character then after reaching a character loops until it hits a space anmd 
//when that happens the counter goes up making it so every time a blank amount of spaces
//then a word it increases word count 
for ( i=0 ; i < state.length() ; i++ )
    {
        if(state[i]==' '){
            do {
            i++;
        }while(state[i]==' ');
        }
        else if(state[i]>=' '){
        do {
            i++;
        }
        while(state[i]>' ');
            
        wordtally++ ;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).